# Can I override any type property in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, overriding

I'm trying to attach my custom types into Express's Request/Response interface.

But some properties are of type `any`, so I'm having really hard to override it.

ex:

```js
// @types/expres-server-static-core
interface Request {
  cookies?: any;
}

// my.ts
import type {Request} from 'express';

type MyCookies = {
  'apple'?: string;
  'banana'?: string;
}

interface MyRequest extends Request {
  cookies: MyCookies
}

// my-usecase.ts
const request: MyRequest = /* */; // MyRequest | Request
request.cookies; // still has any type because MyCookies | any will be any type
```

I know `any`type is the top type of typescript so customized `cookies`property will be ignored.
So I'm using like:

```
const myRequest: MyCookies = req.cookies;
// or
const myRequest = req.cookies as MyCookies;
```

It can solve this problem but I don't want to declare `MyCookies` constants; `req.cookies = MyCookies` is easier to use.

Is there any good way to override `any` type property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not override default properties like that, because at "runtime" there is no guarantee `req.cookies` will exist. So to get correct type, do type narrowing.

```js
const handler = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  if (!req.cookies) throw new Error('unauthorised')
  if (!req.cookies['cookie_name_1'] || typeof req.cookies['cookie_name_1'] !== 'string') throw new Error('unauthorised')
  const cookie_name_1 = req.cookies['cookie_name_1'] // cookie_name_1 is string
}
```

Above one ensures existence of `req.cookies` at both runtime & compilation.

For auto-completion

```
type MyCookies = {
  auth_token?: unknown
  some_token?: unknown
}

const handler = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  if (!req.cookies) throw new Error('unauthorised')
  const cookies = req.cookies as MyCookies 
  if (typeof cookies.auth_token !== 'string') throw new Error('unauthorised')
  console.log(cookies.auth_token) // type is string & IDE will provide autocompletion
}
```

You could override `Request['cookies']` to to have `MyCookies` type but there is huge chance you access those cookie in one place, aka inside a middleware function.

Comment: Thank you!
I'm sorry example code is wrong. I'm trying to get cookies using specific value if exist. And I want to use suggestion just like this:  
`req.cookies[" // IDE will suggest specific cookie keys`

Comment: should I use `function(#) # is ~` type predicates to solve this problem?

Comment: @hee I have updated answer, see if that works. I don't know what `function(#) # is ~` means.

Comment: Thank you for answer & comment!  
`function(#) # is ~` means the typescript type prediction that using `is` keyword. (ex: `function(req: any): req is MyCookies`)

Comment: there is huge chance you access those cookie in one place, aka inside a middleware function

.... sorry but I cannot understand this sentence means(sorry for lack of english skills).
I'm creating the API endpoint, and this middleware function is the middleware that catch request cookies.

Answer (score 0):

How about extending module?

```
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
      cookies: {
       'apple': string;
       'banana': string;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! I already tried to create definition file, but it didn't work(still `any`).
I think declaration can only add property that is not exist.